# Does adding two functions with carry always converge?

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

Let's say I have two functions $f,g: \mathbb{Z} \mapsto  \{0,..,9\}$

and let $ c_0(x) = f(x) + g(x)$
and  $ c_{i+1}(x)  = ( c_i(x) \mod 10) + \lfloor \frac{c_i(x - 1)}{10} \rfloor$.

Does $(c_{i})_{i\geqslant 1}$ eventually converge to a function $c_\infty$?

Comment: Seems like the $f+g$ bit is unnecessary.  Couldn't you start with any function $c_0$ and do the same thing?  You never refer to $f$ or $g$ after step $0$.

Comment: intuitively to me,  it should be true, since this seems  similar to adding real numbers.  but I don't know how to start.

Comment: @Randall you are right, I don't know how that helps though

Comment: In your definition of $c_0$, does $+$ mean ordinary addition or addition mod 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice $$c_1(x) \leq 9 \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{Z}\implies c_1(x)=c_2(x)=c_3(x)= \cdots=c_{\infty}.$$

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Depends on what the $+$ means in the definition of $c_0$, I think.  An output of $c_0$ could be as big as 18.

Comment: Yes, that is for c_0 but if you see c_1 it will be at most 8+1. right ?

Comment: I guess that's right.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I feel stupid for being stuck on this for over an hour. sorry